# Is there any difference in the use of the words deride and disparage?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Although both these words have being treated with little regard for, does one convey something that the other one does not?

> - Our efforts were derided but we carried on the pursuit of success.
> - All that child needed was some encouragement in math, but her mother disparaged her before others so much that the child failed to shine in the test.

Answer (score 1):

*Deride* is more emotionally charged -- it expresses contempt or ridicule. Here are two example sentences from [its online OED definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deride)

> How can I recommend a film that is not only ridiculed by most fans, but also derided by most of the stars of the film?
>
> The other parties have derided the proposal as a plan for a "fantasy island".

"Disparage" generally is less emotional. A couple of example sentences [from the same source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disparage):

> I would say persist and never minimize or disparage yourself or your abilities.
>
> But when you're living with a person all your life, you, unknowingly, tend to disparage his worth.’

Comment: Yes, but surely it is worth mentioning that the specific emotional charge of *deride* is the implication of (scornful) *laughter* carried by the second syllable—which, like the first syllable in *ridicule,* derives from Latin *ridere,* to laugh.